# System.out.printf vs System.out.format

Tags: java, format, printf

Are `System.out.printf` and `System.out.format` totally the same or perhaps they differ in somehow?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`System.out` is a `PrintStream`, and quoting the javadoc for [`PrintStream.printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))

> An invocation of this method of the 
>   form `out.printf(l, format, args)`
>   behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation
>   `out.format(l, format, args)`

Comment: You can simply say "They are exactly the same" and nothing else

Answer (score 18):

No difference.They both behave the [same](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

Answer (score 18):

The actual implementation of both **printf** overloaded forms

```
public PrintStream printf(Locale l, String format, Object ... args) {
    return format(l, format, args);
}
```

and

```
public PrintStream printf(String format, Object ... args) {
        return format(format, args);
}
```

uses the **format** method's overloaded forms

```
public PrintStream format(Locale l, String format, Object ... args)
```

and

```
public PrintStream format(String format, Object ... args)
```

respectively.

Comment: So, can we say use format to avoid one overloaded call?

Comment: @bdchandramohan Calling `format` from within `printf` is not overloading; he is just saying that the two overloaded forms of `printf` call the respective overloaded forms of `format`. Performancewise, I don't think one function call should make a significant difference

Answer (score 0):

The difference between them is that ***printf()*** prints the formatted String into console much like System.out.println() but the ***format()*** method returns a formatted string, which you can store or use the way you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

The key difference between `printf` and `format` methods is:

- [**printf**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)): prints the formatted String into console much like System.out.println() but
- [**format**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)): method return a formatted String, which you can store or use the way you want.

Otherwise nature of use is different according to their functionalities. An example to add leading zeros to a number:

```java
int num = 5;
String str = String.format("%03d", num);  // 005
System.out.printf("Original number %d, leading with zero : %s", num, str);
// Original number 5, leading with zero : 005
```

Comment: OP is referring to `System.out.format` though, not the `String.format` static method.