# How to align my results to look like columns

Tags: java, syntax, formatting

Any ideas on how to line up my results so it looks like a Multiplication Table?
This is a project from school and the teacher wants us to explore different ways to format our code. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class MultiplicationTableBuilder {


    public static void main(String[] args) {



    System.out.println("  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  ");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

    // Nested For loops to build multiplication table
    for(int number1 = 1; number1 <= 10; number1++)
    {
        System.out.printf(number1 + "  |");

        for(int number2 = 1; number2 <= 10; number2++)
        {
            System.out.printf("  " + (number1 * number2));
        }
        System.out.println("  | ");
    }
}
```

Also does anyone else agree with me on feeling like Week 4 is a little early for nested loops and classes (last lesson)? Maybe I'm just getting overwhelmed.

Comment: You can use [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) to pad a number with spaces so that the resulting string will have a specific width. Also, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String#format` or `System.out.printf` to generate formatted output, for example

```
    System.out.printf("%5s %3d %3d %3d %3d %3d %3d %3d %3d %3d %3d%n", "", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");

    // Nested For loops to build multiplication table
    for (int number1 = 1; number1 <= 10; number1++) {
        System.out.printf("%3d | ", number1);

        for (int number2 = 1; number2 <= 10; number2++) {
            System.out.printf("%3d ", (number1 * number2));
        }
        System.out.println("  | ");
    }
```

Output...

```
        1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
-------------------------------------------------
  1 |   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10   | 
  2 |   2   4   6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20   | 
  3 |   3   6   9  12  15  18  21  24  27  30   | 
  4 |   4   8  12  16  20  24  28  32  36  40   | 
  5 |   5  10  15  20  25  30  35  40  45  50   | 
  6 |   6  12  18  24  30  36  42  48  54  60   | 
  7 |   7  14  21  28  35  42  49  56  63  70   | 
  8 |   8  16  24  32  40  48  56  64  72  80   | 
  9 |   9  18  27  36  45  54  63  72  81  90   | 
 10 |  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100   |
```

Take a look at [Java For Complete Beginners - formatted strings](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html) for more details about the format qualifiers

Comment: You shouldnt give the actual code when it is for school work, not a great way to learn especially at the beginning

Comment: @yitzih While a matter of opinion, I don't disagree, given the OP has provided some effort, providing them a working example as a jumping off point isn't necessarily a bad way to learn either, hence the reason I provided a link to the format qualifiers.  I've certainly learnt a lot from "sample" code, probably more then I would have from just studying specifications and code documentation

Comment: @yitzih Let's also face the fact the OP provided the core code.  If they had asked for a means to print a two-d times table, with formatted output, then, absolutely, I'd be asking to see effort, since they've already solved the core issues, provide a simple example to demonstrate how to make it pretty really can't be constituted as "cheating"

Comment: Sorry guys not trying to cheat or anything. My experience with forums usually is answers like "How do you expect us to help you without the code?!". That's why the code is there. I appreciate all the links and responses. I winded up turning this in before seeing all these and now I know I didn't get it right. I didn't use the printf statement and nothing was lined up. Now I know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of providing the code, I want to point you to some examples and documentations:

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-format-example/

Also have a look at the documentation from Oracle:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

The keyword you should be searching for is 'java formatter'

After reading these links, you might wonder what is the difference between the printf method and the format method, here is the answer:

[System.out.printf vs System.out.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234448/system-out-printf-vs-system-out-format)