# How to load text data into a table using Java

Tags: java

I have a text data like

```
name = abc

id = 123

Place = xyz

Details = some texts with two line



name = aaa

id = 54657

Place = dfd

Details = some texts with some lines
```

I need to place them in a table or csv and my output should look like

```
name       id     Place       Details    

abc        123     xyz         Some texts

dfd        54657   dfd         Some texts
```

How can I do this with java?

Comment: Parse the file, so you have the data grouped correctly, you can do this with a `List` of `List` (rows/columns) or even a `List` or `Map`, but I'd personally use a POJO of some kind, but that's me.  Once you have it parsed, you can the format it, using maybe `String.format` to generate the required spacing between each column. As an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229140/writing-data-to-text-file-in-table-format/26229246#26229246) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802139/how-to-align-my-results-to-look-like-columns/28802198#28802198)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code for the CSV version :)  It reads the input file and create a CSV in the format you asked for:

```
try {
            BufferedReader sc = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input2.txt"));

            ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> place = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> details = new ArrayList<>();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = sc.readLine()) !=null) {
                if (!line.trim().equals("")) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    if (line.toLowerCase().contains("name")) {
                        name.add(line.split("=")[1].trim());
                    }
                    if (line.toLowerCase().contains("id")) {
                        id.add(line.split("=")[1].trim());
                    }
                    if (line.toLowerCase().contains("location")) {
                        place.add(line.split("=")[1].trim());
                    }
                    if (line.toLowerCase().contains("details")) {
                        details.add(line.split("=")[1].trim());
                    }
                }
            }

            PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(new File("out.csv"));
            pr.println("name;id;Place;Details;");
            for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
                pr.println(name.get(i) + ";" + id.get(i) + ";" + place.get(i) + ";" + details.get(i) + ";");
            }
            pr.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Sample file content it processes:

```
name = abinhav 
Location =Bangalore 
Id =613636064725610496 
Details = infoodnetwork: Q2 is up. You can still join the Megakitchens in India contest and grab some exciting vouchers. RT if you are enjoying… 

name = Mathi 
Location =Chennai 
Id =613636066474508289 
Details = i am the drifter Of course they can, but the BBC needs a daily negative story on India.
```

Comment: Thank you but when i try to run it shows output in console and it creates an empty file only?? how to over come it

Comment: It is creating an empty file because it did not find the _input.txt_.
`Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));`. Modify the file path in the code if required, but ensure that Java is being able to load the file.

Comment: I think the input file is loaded because it prints the output in console.so  something i have missed and more over when i print (name.get(i)) alone it creates a csv file by listing names in the names column and id place details has empty columns.When i print name id details and place all together i face this problem.

Comment: I ran the code again and it works fine for me.
The code does print the output to the console because of this line: `if (!line.trim().equals("")) { System.out.println(line);`... 
I would suggest you to replace `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` with `e.printStackTrace();` and run the code again. Does it throws any error in the console?

Comment: it does run for me only when i print (name.get(i) + ";" + id.get(i) ); but when i print the whole thing it shows some error in console like java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
 at Transfer.main(Transfer.java:40)

Comment: my input file sample is this one                                                                        name : abinhav  
Location :Bangalore  
Id :613636064725610496  
Details : infoodnetwork: Q2 is up. You can still join the Megakitchens in India contest and grab some exciting vouchers. RT if you are enjoying…  

name : Mathi  
Location :Chennai  
Id :613636066474508289  
Details : i am the drifter Of course they can, but the BBC needs a daily negative story on India.

Comment: Ofc it will throw you errors. The file structure you just provided is different compared to the initial sample you provided. Your second file uses ":" instead of "=" and you use "Location" instead of "Place" as initially indicated. Change the ":" to "=" to properly identify the categories in the file content you posted. I will update the code I posted before to work with those changes.

Comment: if there is any empty space will  skip it automatically??

Comment: Yes it will. This piece of code handles it: `if (!line.trim().equals("")) {`

Answer (score 1):

1. Parse the text file with a `Scanner` (doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html))
2. Create a `DefaultTableModel` (doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)). `DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, new String[]{"name","id","Place","Details"});`, where `data` is a 2D String array with your data.
3. Create a JTable (doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)) with the model you just created. `JTable table = new JTable(model);`
4. Add the table to a `JPanel`, or `JFrame`, with a `JScrollPane` (if needed): `panel.add(new JScrollPane(table));`.

Comment: Thank you Will try and let you know  :)

Comment: Sorry, the answer is not relevant as you don't need to show the data in a GUI. I leave the post though, as it may be useful to users understanding the title of the question as I did.

Comment: Oh okay I am new to it .Is there any other easy way with simple logics or codes??

Answer (score 1):

Reading from text file and writing to csv(comma seperated values) can be achieved using java io.

your logic should once write the headers to a text file with separator as comma and then read the corresponding values from the text may be use split("=") and append to the file with comma separator. You can create new files write the values and  save the file with csv extension

```
try {
            BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input file"));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] strArray = line.split("=");
                // write this to file
                    System.out.println( strArray[1]);


                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: getting an exception any idea how to handle it ??                                                            java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at Table.main(Table.java:14)