# java formatting tabular output

Tags: java, format

so i'm trying to format my output

```
System.out.println("Menu:\nItem#\tItem\t\tPrice\tQuantity");
    for(int i=0;i<stock.length;i++){
        System.out.println((i+1)+"\t"+stock[i].Description + "\t\t"+stock[i].price + "\t"+stock[i].quantity);
```

[the output should be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUeig.png)

[but it comes out as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7V8t.png)

Comment: I'd recommend doing some research into printf and String#format

Comment: Don't count on tabs to format things correctly.  Ever.  Just don't use them.

Answer (score 5):

Java has a nice happy way to print out tables using [System.out.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Here's an example:

```
Object[][] table = new String[4][];
table[0] = new String[] { "Pie", "2.2", "12" };
table[1] = new String[] { "Cracker", "4", "15" };
table[2] = new String[] { "Pop tarts", "1", "4" };
table[3] = new String[] { "Sun Chips", "5", "2" };

System.out.format("%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s\n", "Item#", "Item", "Price", "Quantity");
for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    Object[] row = table[i];
    System.out.format("%-15d%-15s%-15s%-15s\n", i, row[0], row[1], row[2]);
}
```

Results:

```
Item#          Item           Price          Quantity       
0              Pie            2.2            12             
1              Cracker        4              15             
2              Pop tarts      1              4              
3              Sun Chips      5              2
```

Comment: `System.out.prinf` & `System.out.format` are actually the same thing!  As shown in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234448/system-out-printf-vs-system-out-format).

Comment: oh alright i finally did this `System.out.printf("Menu:\n%-10s %-10s %12s %14s\n","Item#","Item","Price","Quantity");
  for(int i=0;i<stock.length;i++){
   System.out.printf("%-10d %-10s %11.2f %8d\n",(i+1),stock[i].Description, stock[i].price, stock[i].quantity);`

Comment: What if I need table borders as well? Vertical `|` between columns.