# Deleting lines from String containing a certain character

Tags: java

any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
code in Java SE 8.

A string is inputted to represent a table.

if a row in the table contains the word NA it must be removed. ex..

if given String  = `"id,name,age,score\n1,Tom,NA,20\n17,Susan,25,15"`
the table would be displayed as follows;

```
id name age score

1  Tom NA 20

5 Susan 25 15
```

As the second row contains 'NA' it needs to be removed. Ps Case matters, so if it says 'na' it doesn't need removed.

I have tried the following:

```
    input = input.replaceAll("NULL,", "");
    String lines[] = input.split("\\r?\\n");
    for (String line : lines) {
        System.out.println(line);
```

The problem is I need to remove the entire row where there is an occurrence of the word 'NA'

any ideas?

Comment: Hello and welcome. What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: try the functions `indexOf` to find the start index of each occurence, and `replace` to replace it with an empty string

Comment: Hi , apologies, post updated above . I need to remove the entire row where there is an occurrence of the word 'NA' but I'm not sure how to do this on a string that represents a table. thanks

Comment: @amcc12345 I'm not sure how the fact that it represents a table is relevant. You can just search for "NA" in the string (with `contains`) and if it's there you just don't print the string.

Comment: @amcc12345 ah, now I see where the "table" concept fits in. Once you decide whether or not to show the row, you can split the row on `","` and then follow [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036396/java-formatting-tabular-output) to see how to print the rows in tabular form.

Comment: Hi thanks,I think i have over complicated the question, if its ok i will post a new simplified question and make it more clear what I need to do.

Comment: @amcc12345 if you do, please make sure the answer is not already around, that you ask one, focused question and that you are very clear. Also, if you do, please delete this one.

Comment: Thanks, will do. btw it wont let me delete this question as people have responded

Answer (score 1):

I recommend splitting the String with String.split('\n'); That will return an Array you can work with much easier. With that you can just filter the array for Strings that include NA.