# java formatting tabular output using picocli

Tags: java, format, picocli

I'm looking to format this code:

```
Object[][] table = new String[4][];
        table[0] = new String[] { "Pie", "2.2", "12" };
        table[1] = new String[] { "Cracker", "4", "15" };
        table[2] = new String[] { "Pop tarts", "1", "4" };
        table[3] = new String[] { "Sun Chips", "5", "2" };

        String itemId = CommandLine.Help.Ansi.AUTO.string("@|bold,green,underline ItemId|@");

        System.out.format("%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s\n", itemId, "Item", "Price", "Quantity");
        for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
            Object[] row = table[i];
            System.out.format("%-15d%-15s%-15s%-15s\n", i, row[0], row[1], row[2]);
        }
```

This is a spin-off example from an earlier stack exchange question ([java formatting tabular output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036396/java-formatting-tabular-output))

However, with my markup string, rather than getting properly [tabbed headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq2NI.png),
I'm getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU67Y.png) instead.

What's going on?

Comment: Are the links to the images correct? Is the "properly tabbed headers" link actually the incorrect output?

Comment: Whoops! Yes, that's correct. Let me edit the post. @JimGarrison

Answer (score 1):

strange, looks good to me.

code:

````
import picocli.CommandLine; 
public static void main(String... args) {
        Object[][] table = new String[4][];
        table[0] = new String[]{"Pie", "2.2", "12"};
        table[1] = new String[]{"Cracker", "4", "15"};
        table[2] = new String[]{"Pop tarts", "1", "4"};
        table[3] = new String[]{"Sun Chips", "5", "2"};

        String itemId = CommandLine.Help.Ansi.AUTO.string("@|bold,green,underline ItemId|@");

        System.out.format("%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s\n", itemId, "Item", "Price", "Quantity");
        for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
            Object[] row = table[i];
            System.out.format("%-15d%-15s%-15s%-15s\n", i, row[0], row[1], row[2]);

        }
    } ```

output: 

ItemId         Item           Price          Quantity       
0              Pie            2.2            12             
1              Cracker        4              15             
2              Pop tarts      1              4              
3              Sun Chips      5              2
````